# Que vem a ser a "chibaria"?

Tags: português-europeu, significado-em-contexto, gíria

Na canção [Telemóveis do Conan Osíris](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DWoA-7kF5R4) temos estes versos intrigantes (1m44s)

> E quem mata quem? Mata? Eu nem sei.
>   A chibaria nunca viu nascer ninguém.

Eu nunca tinha ouvido falar em *chibaria*, mas para mim seria uma grupo de chibos, ou seja de delatores ou, em bom vernáculo, bufos. E é isto que vem em [*chibaria* no Priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/chibaria). Como é que isto se insere no contexto da canção é que eu não estou a ver. [Neste vídeo com a letra em inglês](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L1wIrV_eT8s) (não faço ideia quem é que traduziu), *chibaria* vem traduzido em ‘sensationalists’; não vejo nem onde é que foram buscar esta ideia nem que sentido é que faz no contexto. E claro, literalmente, *chibo* é ‘cabrito’ — será que o Conan quis dizer ‘cabrões’? Ou está só a rir-se à custa do pessoal?

Seja como for, fico com a sensação que algo me está a escapar aqui. Alguém conhece outros significados de *chibaria*, em especial que façam sentido na canção?

Comment: Não entendi porque chibaria no sentido de delatores não se encaixaria na música: "Quem mata? Eu não sei. Não sou/há delator". O que não está claro para mim é o "nunca viu nascer ninguém".

Comment: @stafusa, não sei se ouviste a canção toda, mas o "matar" é figurativo ("fui ver se matava a saudade, e vai na volta quem morre sou eu"); não é caso de polícia.

Comment: Isto está claro, @Jacinto, e penso que ele afirmar que não será delator é coerente com a parte anterior da letra que diz "Quando eu souber, eu não ligo a mais ninguém", mas é claro que é um texto poético, aberto a interpretação.

Comment: @stafusa, parece-me isso estranho. Nós chamamos "chibo" a alguém quando essa pessoa vai revelar algo que ela sabe que nós queríamos manter em segredo. E neste caso ele não sabe quem mata quem, logo não há nada para revelar; ou melhor, o que poderia ser revelado ele já revelou: ele parece estar a falar duma relação que acabou mal, e ele não sabe quem "mata" (de desgosto, imagino) quem; isto é, admite a possibilidade de um, o outro, ou ambos serem o culpado; portanto já revelou tudo. "Não ligo a mais ninguém" para mim significa que ele não incomoda mais ninguém com telefonemas ou  >>

Comment: >> não vai querer se envolver com mais ninguém ("não ligar" = 'não se interessar por').

Comment: @Jacinto, para mim é bem claro que i) ou o cantor ou a saudade é que vai morrer; ii) durante a música ele não sabe a resposta (e agora creio que o trecho da chibaria significa que não há quem possa dizer/delatar) ; iii) no final ele supera a saudade ("a saudade tá morta / Quem mandou a flecha fui eu").

Comment: Só por curiosidade em Braga existe um restaurante que se chama "Chibaria".

Comment: @JorgeB., tens de lá ir perguntar, talvez eles saibam interpretar a canção do Conan :)

Comment: Nunca ouviste falar em chibaria? Essa palavra é muito comum em Lisboa e entre os mitras.

Comment: @bad_coder, Nunca. E eu trabalho em Lisboa. E significa o quê afinal? Alguma coisa que faça sentido na canção? Eu lembrei-me que *chibo* é muito próximo de *queixinhas*, o que me sugeriu uma interpretação especulativa. Vê primeiros dois comentários à resposta do Stafusa.

Comment: Hei @Jacinto, olha esta desconstrução da música... https://aminoapps.com/c/genesis-portugal/page/blog/desmistificando-a-letra-telemoveis-conan-osiris/bNdX_epmToue8dGxZW78rZvaB3xKa7VEX2

Answer (score 1):

> A chibaria nunca viu nascer ninguém.

A expressão *"ver nascer"*, pode ser usado no sentido "viu-me nascer" ou "viu-me crescer" (não muito frequente). Aplicado a pessoas é alguém que nos conheceu, um vizinho, uma relação familiar, ou um conhecido que sabe de nós em alguma medida relevante. Mas da forma ainda mais comum (acho na canção é usado com duplo sentido, sendo este último mais óbvio) significa *"ver nascer"* alguma coisa, produzir alguma coisa, contribuir para o seu desenvolvimento. (O *"nascimento de um projecto"*, neste caso aplicado a uma pessoa.)

Portanto, a delação leva ao duplo sentido. Por um lado a chibaria não conhece ninguém, não viu crescer ninguém, não teve essa familiaridade que leva a saber dar valor à pessoa (por princípio). No segundo sentido -duplo- a delação não contribui activamente, para bem nenhum, não traz nada, não cria nada, e não verá o bem do outro.

Vistos os sentidos possíveis, o contexto da canção é a sua relação com "o telemóvel". Necessária alusão à vida social, a indiscrição, o mexerico, a inconfidência - são as causas clássicas que levam ao clássico tema e dilema central à música: Cortar com a vida social -com os problemas- cortando com o telemóvel.

Por *"nunca ter visto nascer ninguém"* não sabe o que é querer bem ao outro, nem verá esse bem por contributo da sua própria acção. É, nesse sentido, reflexivo.

> E quem mata quem? Mata? Eu nem sei.

Esta é simples e clássica:

> [`Proverbs 18:21`](https://bible.usccb.org/bible/proverbs/18)
>
> ```
> Death and life are in the power of the tongue;
>
> those who choose one shall eat its fruit.
> ```

Quanto a *"chibaria"* é não só comum em Lisboa como noutras partes do país. O sentido vem de cabra e cabrão, que dispensam explicações. Terá estado mais em voga em certos meios sociais do que outros - nunca ouvi essa palavra das gerações mais antigas.

Mas é hoje, de facto, transversal. Se tivesse de especular diria o insulto ter origem provável em meios mais rurais migrando para os meios urbanos, onde pegou e tornou-se lugar comum.

Um termo menos elegante, penso que nos tempos da PIDE a palavra era menos usada -rara senão inédita. As variantes mais comuns desse tempo como *"cacique"* (os caciques eram informadores civis da PIDE, equiparáveis aos anteriores *"familiares do santo ofício"*) e *"bufo"*(informal) têm, discutivelmente, mais fineza (no palavreado, claro).

**EDIT**:

No dicionário H. Michaelis (não é a Drª Carolina, é a irmã) figura o verbete com esta entrada:

```
Chibança, Chibant||aria, ~eria, ~e, ~ice, ~ismo.

(...)

Chibar, v. n. 

    Grosssprecher, Renomimisten vielen, prahlen, grossthun.

H. Michaelis
Neues Wörterbuch der portugiesischen und deutschen Sprache mit besonderer
Berücksichtigung der technischen Ausdrücke des Handels und der Industrie,
der Wissenschaften und Künste und der Umgangssprache.
F. A. Brockhaus, Leipzig, Lisboa 1905
```

Portanto a palavra já existia, com o significado de engrandecer-se, gabar-se. Só mudou de sentido.

Comment: Eu já tinha especulado que "nunca viu nascer ninguém" significasse no contexto 'não conseguir nada de bom', mas nunca ouvi isso com esse sentido.

Comment: @Jacinto occoreu-me agora, seria preciso encontrar a ocorrência mais antiga de "chibo" enquanto adjectivo (alias, "chibante") como sinónimo de "bufo" num dicionário ou publicação para poder datar de alguma maneira o verbo "chibar". Encontrei "Chibaria" (ou chibar?!) num livro do Camilo Castelo Branco, mas acho que não era no sentido que a canção sugere. Alias, pode o sentido da canção não ser a delação - é o problema de propor-nos a perceper o sentido de uma coisa feita para não ser entendida.

Comment: Bad-coder, a minha pergunta é precisamente se *chibaria* tem algum outro significado que encaixe ali. A minha especulação, já depois de fazer a pergunta, foi que fosse ’queixinhas’, e que ele ao dizer que não sabe quem matou quem está a recusar queixar-se da outra pessoa e que recusa porque os queixinhas (os chibos = a chibaria) não conseguem nada de bom. Para mim o queixinhas e o chibo não são bem a mesma coisa, mas têm algo em comum. Quanto a data *chibo* e *chibar*, não me parece necessário. Só quero saber os significados possíveis de *chibaria*.

Comment: @Jacinto o outro significado possivel de *"chibaria"* -que vi num qualquer dicionário (e as utilizações mais antigas da palavra), é "insistir à cabeçada"- Uma espência de obstinação sem razão que resulta só do mau feitio e tendência para o confronto, insistir em chatear e causar confronto com gratuitidade fútil, quase espêcie de machismo em prevalecer verbalmente por via da opinião custe o que custar (fica assim esgotada a semântca).

Comment: @Jacinto quanto a tua elaboração no sentido de "queixinhas". A música como um todo tem poucas palavras, começa por ligar para o "ceu" e termina em "flecha" (forte sugestão ao *Cupido*) De resto só tem a palavra *chibaria* e um conjunto de acções com o telele. Se alguma coisa pode ser extraido, é tema romántico ou subjacente judicial - "as escutas". Mas, o sentido social (que referi e para onde a chibaria remete), das inconfidências também é uma forta possibilidade, a queixa ou o desabafo que depois o deixa preso pela língua e arrisca arruinar a relação (morte da relação, depois não vê nascer).

Answer (score 0):

Na minha interpretação significa de fato "delatores", e estaria implícito:

> E quem mata quem? Mata? Eu nem sei.
>   A chibaria nunca viu nascer ninguém [ *que possa responder* ].

Ou seja, ele não sabe (nesse momento da música) se a saudade o matará ou ele a ela e aqui afirma que não há quem saiba, "não há quem possa delatar (quem é o futuro assassino - ele ou a saudade)".

Comment: Nessa tua interpretação, o chibo seria, não quem denunciaria o assassino, mas quem denunciasse alguém que pudesse identificar o assassino. Eh pá! altamente rebuscado! E a adição do [que possa responder] parece-me arbitrária. Há uma coisa que me ocorreu. *Chibo* não é bem mas anda próximo de *queixinhas*. Ele pergunta "quem mata quem?"e com "eu nem sei" ele abstém-se de acusar a outra pessoa de o estar a matar (eu imagino a (ex-)namorada); ou seja ele não é queixinhas; >>

Comment: >> "a chibaria [= os queixinhas?] nunca viu nascer ninguém" será uma maneira de dizer que os queixinhas não conseguem nada de bom? não prestam? Na canção parece haver uma progressão em que ele começa por quase acusar a outra pessoa ("se a vida ligar ... e tu não tiveres coragem de atender), depois duvida ("quem mata quem? eu nem sei"), e por fim admite que é ele o culpado ("a saudade tá morta, quem mandou a flecha fui eu"). Eu uso *chibo* e *queixinhas* diferentemente, mas isto são gírias, *chibo*  especialmente, e o uso pode variar.

Comment: @Jacinto "o chibo seria [...] quem denunciasse alguém que pudesse identificar o assassino" - Nope, não é como entendo. Penso que significa que ninguém pode dizer, nem o próprio intérprete. Mas posso estar errado. Para mim a interpretação do texto ainda é claramente a que coloquei, mas nada fiz além de ouvir a música e ler a letra algumas vezes e checar uns dicionários e outros textos - não tenho vivência com essa gíria (ou o pt-PT em geral), nem com as obras do compositor, e poesia não é meu forte. :-) Ou seja, não boto a mão no fogo pela minha interpretação, mas não vi nenhuma outra melhor.

Comment: Stafusa, então tu interpetas "A chibaria nunca viu nascer ninguém que possa responder" (à pergunta 'quem mata quem'). Alguém que pudesse responder, identificaria o "assassino"; um chibo que tivesse visto nascer esse alguém (se tivesse, mas não viu), estaria em posição de denunciar (chibar) esse alguém; não estaria em posição de diretamente denunciar o assassino. Também não me parece que "delatar/chibar" faça sentido no contexto duma relação pessoal, que é o que me parece que está subjacente; "queixar-se" já faria.

Comment: @Jacinto, deixando de lado a questão sobre qual seria a interpretação correta e focando por agora apenas em qual exatamente é a minha, porque parece ainda não estar claro: entendo que "A chibaria nunca viu nascer ninguém [que possa responder]" significa que não há entre eles (os que denunciam) alguém que saiba a resposta (e portanto possa denunciar) - i.e., ou ninguém sabe a resposta, ou quem sabe (Deus ou quem quer que atendesse no céu) não dirá.

Comment: @Jacinto Concordo que o uso de "chibaria" nesse contexto não é óbvio, natural, mas é proposital - telefonar para o céu para descobrir se ele morrerá de saudade (como ele coloca no início da música) também não é usual - talvez seja uma referência a rezar, ou um ato de desespero. Talvez o telefone aqui simbolize o se relacionar - então "quebrar o telemóvel" é deixar de se relacionar... Mas já justifiquei mais do que o suficiente minha interpretação - acredito que a leitura de poesia é particularmente subjetiva, então talvez eu esteja enganado, mas talvez apenas tenhamos percepções diferentes.

Comment: Então para ti é "A chibaria nunca viu nascer ninguém [que possa responder]" = "ainda não nasceu um chibo (alguém entre os chibos) [que possa responder]"? Isto só me ocorreu agora depois do teu penúltimo comentário. A leitura que eu fiz da tua resposta foi, os chibos não te podem indicar alguém que saiba responder (o resultado final é o mesmo, isso nunca esteve em dúvida, não consegues obter a resposta; mas fica estranho, porque introduz uma cadeia de informantes, a pessoa que pudesse responder, e o chibo que pudesse indicar essa pessoa).

Comment: Exato. @Jacinto

Comment: Talvez fosse melhor clarificar, então. Sempre é uma conceção mais elegante do que minha leitura inicial, de não haver chibo que pudesse indicar quem respondesse. Continuo a achar estranho, mais até na tua interpretação de "quem mata quem?" do que na minha. Só para certificar, *matar saudade*, em Portugal, significa 'satisfazer a saudade'  tipo, tens saudades dum velho amigo, vais visitá-lo para matar saudade (mesmo no Brasil, não?). Então se "quem mata quem?" é 'mato eu a saudade ou morro eu', quem respondesse estaria a ser meu amigo, não seria nunca chibo; o chibo é muito pejorativo;  >>

Comment: >> é alguém que me prejudica; é desleal, ou no mínimo tem maus fígados. Eu vejo "quem mata quem?" de forma diferente. Ele tem saudades de alguém, digamos, da ex-namorada. Tenta telefonar-lhe para ver se mata a saudade, mas não consegue que ela atenda. Então "quem mata quem" é, mata-o ela a ele de saudade, de desgosto (= fá-lo sofrer) ou é ele que a faz sofrer? Nesta interpretação, *chibar* continua a ser estranho, mas queixar-se já encaixa.

Comment: @Jacinto Sim, no Brasil, "matar as saudades" tem o mesmo significado e talvez não combine muito com o texto (ou poderia combinar? quem sabe ele conseguiu rever a pessoa e matou as saudades nesse sentido mesmo), por outro lado, "matar as saudades" com uma flecha, como ele canta, também é estranho (ou seria a flecha uma mensagem de texto? :-) ).

Comment: Ele diz é "a saudade está morta, quem mandou a flecha fui eu".  Nós aqui dizemos, "fui à terra matar saudades", "então já mataste as saudades?" mas nunca "a saudade está morta". Para mim, "a saudade está morta" = 'já não há saudade, extinguiram-se os sentimentos bons que existiram', e ele é o culpado. Condiz com a cara de desalento com que ele canta essa parte.

Comment: @Jacinto. Boa. Tinha estranhado o "está morta" um pouco, e essa parece uma interpretação bem possível.